# Server Backup Options?

Tags: apache-2.2, backup, mac-osx-server, incremental-backup

I currently have a dedicated server running Apache (I can supply more specs if needed), but I'm trying to setup automatic full backups to run every night. Preferably I'd like to be able to put them on our mac mini server every night. Is there any way to do this?

Getting a secondary disk on the server is not an option unfortunately.

Comment: Putting a second disk into the server is not a backup anyway, but I would consider this a product recommendation and therefore to be off-topic (see the [FAQ]).

Answer (score 1):

[rsync](http://rsync.samba.org/) included on most Linux distributions by default (or usually always in a software repository with your distro) will allow you to copy/backup files from your Apache server to a mac mini.

This [guide](http://blog.interlinked.org/tutorials/rsync_time_machine.html) gives you a time machine like backup on a Linux system using rsync, which I've used with great success in the past.

Comment: I'll definitely take a look at rsync, I forgot to mention that I'm using a remote server, but the mac mini server is local.

Comment: Rsync will work in both directions, as long as you have SSH available.

Comment: Sweet, so to be clear I can rsync from my remote dedicated via SSH to my Mac Mini Server every night?

Comment: It would be more advisable from a security perspective to do a "pull" rsync from your Mac Mini.

Comment: Alright sounds good, thank you, what would be the proper way to set this up? If possible compression would be desired.